# Does a locked mutex protect the condition_variable as well as the data?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following implementation of the [this_thread::sleep_for()](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/555b85416e4e162d) function. It is from Stroustrup's book, "CPL", 4, pg 1232. I have modified it by (i) renaming it and (ii) separating the function from client-code:

```
#include <chrono>       /// milliseconds
#include <mutex>        /// mutex, unique_lock
#include <condition_variable>   /// condition_variable

/// declarations ...

namespace ext
{
   void sleep_for(int ms);
}


/// implementation ...

void ext::sleep_for(int ms)
{
   std::mutex mtx;
   std::condition_variable timercv;

   /// acquire mtx
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {mtx};

   /// release and reacquire mutex
   timercv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds {ms});
}  // implicitly release mtx
```

Stroustrup states:

> The mutex protects wait_for() against data races. The wait_for() releases its mutex as it goes to sleep and reacquires it as its thread is unblocked.

I'd like to ask:
1) By saying that the `mutex` protects `wait_for()` against data races, I assume Stroustrup is referring to the `condition_variable` itself, right?
2) Why does the `condition_variable` require protection from concurrent access? It is a *local* variable, rather than a global variable. Each invocation of the `ext::sleep_for()` function by a thread would have a separate copy of the `condition_variable`.
3) In this program, there is no global data to protect (such as a ready flag, etc.) Does the `mutex` protect the `condition_variable`? If so, from what? As I have stated, a separate copy would be accessed by each thread invoking this function.

**-- EDIT --**
Here's my explanation of why a `mutex` and a `condition_variable` are used in this code:
1) The `mutex` is needed, to obtain a lock on it.
2) The `condition_variable` releases the lock on the mutex, goes to sleep for the specified period and then reacquires the lock.

Comment: Your code an error and I don't know if it was because of transcriptionor in the source (sometimes Stroustrup is working in pre-standard C++).  `wait_for` should be passed a 3rd argument `[]{return false;}` to fix it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont nope, the predicate is optional there's an overload that just takes a lock and a time.

Comment: You're right. This is a bad example. You are correct about the local cv and mutex. No global data means there's nothing to protect with locks. Additionally, as @Yakk-AdamNevraumont said, it's missing a predicate that will protect it from a spurious wakeup. (The time is a MAX time, but is allowed to be less time). Maybe there's some weird use case for this but I don't know it. 

The original use case for condition variables was to allow a thread holding a mutex to sleep (aka block) and release the mutex atomically. Then later wake and re-acquire the mutex atomically.

Comment: @Yakk, I have edited the post to add a possible explanation for why a `mutex` and a `condition_variable` are used in this code.

Comment: @ssteven I understand the code; the problem is the code has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. Condition variables are permitted to spuriously wake up; you are responsible for handling that case.  Nothing in the above code handles it.  There is an easy fix here:

```
timercv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds {ms}, []{return false;});
```

now, any early wakeup will be rejected.

This is still an extremely strange use of condition variables.  Usually they are used to communicate between one or more threads.  In that case, the mutex and the condition variable and the thing the condition variable checks form a triple.

Stroustrup appears to be talking about a more typical case.

In this more typical case, the mutex protects access to the thing the condition variable checks, and must be locked in order to perform some operations on the condition variable.  As these are low level threading primitives you should either follow standard patterns which work, or you have to understand exactly what every operation does and what guarantees it provides and prove your code is correct.  Any simplification will be in the form of "lies told to children", and designing new use patterns based off lies will not work with any reliability.

The exact specs are described in the standard, and those are the specs you should refer to.  Note that the specs changed between standard revisions.

In short, you should find validated use patterns and use them, then encapsulate them, and never touch them.

A simpler way to write sleep for is:

```
void ext::sleep_for(int ms) {
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(mtx);
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(mtx, std::defer_lock_t{});
  lock2.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds {ms});
}  // implicitly release mtx
```

which doesn't have nearly as complex a set of conditions, and uses simpler primitives.

Comment: Adam, I appreciate your implementation of sleep_for(). Why are 2 locks needed? Isn't one enough?

Comment: @ssteven One to make the mutex locked the other to sleep on the locked mutex.  I did forget to defer lock it. Fixed.